# replace contents between XML tag

Tags: regex, xml, bash, replace, sed

I have a XML file with

```
<RangeType>3</RangeType>
<RangeAmount>1</RangeAmount>
<FromDate>2016/8/12 00:00:00</FromDate>
<ToDate>2016/8/12</ToDate>
<SyncOnSelect>0</SyncOnSelect>
<RunEvery>0</RunEvery>
```

I want to replace Fromdate content (maybe anydate) to 2016/09/21, I plan to do this everyday, to change it to today

```
<RangeType>3</RangeType>
<RangeAmount>1</RangeAmount>
<FromDate>2016/09/21</FromDate>
<ToDate>2016/8/12</ToDate>
<SyncOnSelect>0</SyncOnSelect>
<RunEvery>0</RunEvery>
```

I tried

```
sed 's/<FromDate>*<\/FromDate>/<FromDate>2016\/09\/21<\/FromDate>/g'
```

How do I do this?

Comment: replace <FromDate> content to 2016/09/21

Comment: This is not HTML, this is XML. Regardless, use an XML parser.

Comment: just a typo in command you tried: `*` should be `.*`

Comment: It works, Thank you very much Sundeep

Comment: @lwhuang, only for a very poor value of "works". `sed` can't understand XML syntax: For instance, your document would still be completely valid XML (with exactly the same meaning to any compliant parser) if you had a newline or a space between `<FromDate` and `>`, or no newlines at all anywhere in your file, but either of those changes would mess up your `sed`-based approach.

Comment: @rockerest, ...we have closer duplicates than that one -- it doesn't have *anything* to do with editing, after all. Thus, in this context, it's just an admonishment without any example of *how* to do things better, whereas there are clear Q&A entries showing how to use XSLTProc, XMLStarlet, Python-interpreter XML libraries, &c. from bash to correctly edit XML files from shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Use a real XML parser, such as [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html):

```
newValue=$(date '+%Y/%m/%d 00:00:00')
xmlstarlet ed -u '//FromDate' -v "$newValue" \
   <in.xml >out.xml
```